# How to read the roles array from Meteor.users collection in Client?

Tags: meteor

I use the package: [alanning/meteor-roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles)

I am building a simple UI for Admin to manage other users roles. A user can have more than one role, I am using checkbox to choose roles.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to access the roles array that is stored in `Meteor.users` collection in my Client code.

In a helper, I am checking the user roles in order to load it in the UI as checked...

Note: this HTML is accessible for all users now just to test it. It will be available only for Admin after I get it to work. So I noticed that this code works only for signed in user and not for all users.

My code:

HTML:

```html
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="userRole" value="r1" checked="{{isRoleChecked 'r1'}}">r1</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="userRole" value="r2" checked="{{isRoleChecked 'r2'}}">r2</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="userRole" value="r3" checked="{{isRoleChecked 'r3'}}">r3</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="userRole" value="r4" checked="{{isRoleChecked 'r4'}}">r4</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="userRole" value="r5" checked="{{isRoleChecked 'r5'}}">r5</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="userRole" value="r6" checked="{{isRoleChecked 'r6'}}">r6</label>
```

isRoleChecked helper: (Client code)

```js
isRoleChecked: function(value) {

  // didn't work
  roles = Roles.getRolesForUser(this._id);
  if (roles) {
    for(var i=0; i < roles.length; i++) {
      if (roles[i] == value){
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Meteor does not publish data outside `profile` for `Meteor.users` collection, except for the current user. The rationale is to make sure sensitive data is always hidden.

> If the autopublish package is installed, information about all users on the system is published to all clients. This includes* `username`, `profile`, and any fields in services that are meant to be public (eg `services.facebook.id`, `services.twitter.screenName`). Additionally, when using autopublish more information** is published for the currently logged in user, including access tokens.

(source: https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users)

* means other fields are *excluded*, therefore `roles` is not published by `autopublish`.

** this includes `roles` field for the current user.

That is why your code works only for the current user.

Therefore you just need to setup a publication (and subscribe to it) that explicitly [sends the `roles` field](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#fieldspecifiers) of your users to the client:

```js
Meteor.publish('usersRoles', function () {
  return Meteor.users.find(mySelector, {
    fields: {
      roles: 1
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm sill using autopublish package @ghybs

Comment: The behaviour described in the above answer is especially relevant with `autopublish` (see https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users). Otherwise, you would not even have other users `profile` data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to publish the `roles` key:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('roles',() => {
  if ( Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId,['Admin']) {
    return Meteor.users.find({},{fields: {roles: 1}});
  } else this.ready();
});
```

And subscribe to that on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('roles');
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I tried the code you wrote about the publish but it didn't work for some reason. The code I that worked:

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('roles',() => {
      return Meteor.users.find({},{fields: {roles: 1}});
  });
}

Comment: I had assumed you were using the *alanning:roles* package.

Comment: yes, I've stated above that I'm using alanning:roles package... but for some reason the code you provided didn't work unfortunately. but I really appreciate your help Thanks so much