# Roles.userIsInRole not working

Tags: meteor, alanning-roles

I'm building a Meteor application with React. My problem is the `alanning:roles` package doesn't seem to be working as intended.

There are no console errors but basically the following code does not work as intended.

```
const composer = (props, onData) => {
    const loggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn()
    const loggedInUserId = Meteor.userId()
    console.log(loggedInUserId)
    let authenticated
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUserId, ['admin']))
        authenticated = 'admin';
    else if (Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUserId, ['school']))
        authenticated = 'school'
    else if (Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUserId, ['teacher']))
        authenticated = 'teacher'
    else
        authenticated = 'anonymous'
    console.log(authenticated)
    onData(null, {
        loggingIn,
        authenticated
    })
}
```

The `loggedInUserId` variable successfully shows the logged in user's `id` in the first `console.log()`. However, `authenticated`'s value is always `anonymous` regardless of what user is logged in.

I can confirm that the `loggedInUserId` definitely matches a user which is in the relative role but the result always remains the same.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you run `Roles.addUsersToRoles` before ?

Comment: Yes, I did that in my fixtures.

Comment: What is the output from `Roles.getRolesForUser(loggedInUserId)` ?

Comment: Ah it just returns an empty array.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436117/how-to-read-the-roles-array-from-users-collection/43436561#43436561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing my `composer` to this:

```
const composer = (props, onData) => {
    const loggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn()
    const loggedInUserId = Meteor.userId()

    let authenticated
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUserId, 'admin', 'default-group'))
        authenticated = 'admin';
    else if (Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUserId, 'school', 'default-group'))
        authenticated = 'school'
    else if (Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUserId, 'teacher', 'default-group'))
        authenticated = 'teacher'
    else
        authenticated = 'anonymous'

    onData(null, {
        loggingIn,
        authenticated
    })
}
```

When not specifying a `group` when assigning roles it automatically assigns the role to the `default-group`.