# How can I add new field to Meteor.users()?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a button that inserts new user to `Meteor.users()`.

In the server I have this method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'addUser': function(user) {
        return Accounts.createUser(user)
    }
})
```

And in the client (After button is clicked):

```
var newUser = {
            email: t.find('#email').value,
            password: t.find('#pwd').value,
            profile: { name: t.find('#name').value, group: t.find('#userType').value },
            roles: checkedRoles // I can successfully console.log(checkedRoles) which is an array of strings.
        }

        Meteor.call('addUser', newUser, function(error){
            if(error){
                sweetAlert(error)
            } else {
                sweetAlert('User Successfully Added')
            }
        })
```

Using the above code, the user is added but without the `roles` field.

My question is, how can I add the `roles` field to the newly added user?

Comment: Have you tried Alanning:Roles package?

Comment: I suspect this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436117/how-to-read-the-roles-array-from-users-collection

Comment: @Orozcorp yes, I am using alnning:roles package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [alanning:roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) package:

`meteor add alanning:roles`

then (in your server side method):

`const userId = Accounts.createUser(user);`

`Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, user.roles);`